# Python context managers in sqlalchemy session class (please explain)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, contextmanager

I am having a deeper look at the Session class inside the Sqlalchemy library in `sqlalchemy.orm.session.py` ([link here](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/main/lib/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py)) and i see this block inside the Session class at line 1170:

```
@util.contextmanager
def _maker_context_manager(self):
    with self:
        with self.begin():
            yield self
```

I don't understand the syntax and what it does. Why is there a `with self:` at the start? Can we use `with` and any class? Can someone please explain this and how it is useful in the context of sqlalchemy session?

Comment: `with` must be used with a context manager. So, you know `self` is a context manager, otherwise it wouldn't work. And you know `self.begin()` returns a context manager, for the same reason. A context manager is just an object with `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods that are called when the body of the `with` statement is entered and exited. So, you know those objects have those methods. Googling "Python context managers" will find a number of further explanations of what context managers are, how they work, and how to use them.

Answer (score 0):

`with self:` points to `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods. These methods act as context managers. Here's an excerpt from [Python's doc on context managers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#context-manager-types):

> Python’s with statement supports the concept of a runtime context defined by a context manager. This is implemented using a pair of methods that allow user-defined classes to define a runtime context that is entered before the statement body is executed and exited when the statement ends:
>
> - `contextmanager.__enter__()`: Enter the runtime context and return either this object or another object related to the runtime context [...]
> - `contextmanager.__exit__(exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb)`: Exit the runtime
>   context [...].

From `Session` ([here](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/5c2af38dce17a7218137e26d84911cdb36e87811/lib/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py#L1425)):

```
def __enter__(self: _S) -> _S:
    return self

def __exit__(self, type_: Any, value: Any, traceback: Any) -> None:
    self.close()
```

Here, `__enter__` returns the instance of the class. And `__exit__` helps with graceful termination (closing the session when you exit the scope). Acting as internal context managers.